# Regular expression for numbers and dots validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

var string = 1.123.1.2.6.

Validation Rules

1. The sting will **begin** with **a number or a dot**
2. The string **end** with **a number or a dot**
3. The number may **1 to 3 character length** like (1 or 12 or 123)
4. **Continuous dots are not allowed** ( like this **..**)

   ```
   <script>

       var str = "1.123.1.2.6.";

       var patt2 = '^(([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?\.+([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?))*\.?$';

       document.write(str.match(patt2));

   </script>
   ```

Comment: this is called OID for additional info  http://oid-info.com/get/2.1.0.0.0

Comment: 1) No specific question has been asked. 2) Is this in PHP or JS? What's the `performance` tag for? 3) Absolutely no attempt of your own given -- did you try, or do you expect ready-made code? I wish I could downvote more than once.

Comment: I agree with @Jon's points. You should at least put some effort first before asking a "gimme teh codez" question.

Comment: it's a question I couldn't find any solution .. this is what i tried   ^(([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?\.+([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?))*\.?$

Comment: /^(?!.*\.{2,})(\.?(\d|[1-9]\d{1,2})\.?)+$/ right answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\A\.?([0-9]{1,3}\.)+[0-9]{0,3}\z
```

Comment: The last quantifier should be `{0,3}` to match ending with a dot.

Comment: Not sure if it is correct but it's virtually the expression I had in mind so +1

Comment: Something like `/^\.?([0-9]{1,3}\.)+[0-9]{0,3}$/` for a JS regex literal.

Comment: ^(([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?\.+([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?))*\.?$ this js is working only one problem is it's accepting more than one dot's how to fix this

Comment: yes it's working but it's accepts more than one character also.. like this .123456.2.3.  . But it's working thank's to post this " ^(?!.*\.{2,})(\.?(\d|[1-9]\d{1,2})\.?)+$ "